# Overlapping with notifications bar on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I developed an Algorithms App (for [iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/algorithms-app/id539362701) and [Mac](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/algorithms-app/id577563313)). Recently I noticed that my iPad program is overlapping with the top notifications bar on iPad, leaving a white gap below. See the following screenshot. This issue was not there in earlier versions.

How do I fix this ?
Did something change in the recent versions of iOS / Objective-C / Xcode ?

[image]

Comment: Are you doing something to the Status Bar? Looks like your view is underneath it in the upper-left corner. And the gap looks like the same height as the Status Bar. Did it slide up somehow? Just a guess. Things always change a little between iOS versions; needing to tweak the UI is common.

Comment: I am not doing anything with the Status Bar. Yes. It slide up somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project supports on ios 7 onwards but you done UIDesign in ios 6. Just change your storyboard to iOS 7 and adjust your UI

Comment: I changed my 'iOS Deployment Target' to 8.0 and did a clean build. I am still seeing the same overlapping issue. How do I change the storyboard to latest iOS ?

Comment: Go to Storyboard click on resolve auto layout issues (symbol is like this |-.-|)

Comment: I cannot find this 'Resolve auto layout issues' button in the storyboard (even after selecting the view). I am using Xcode 6.0.1. May be the button is moved to somewhere else :(

Comment: I resolved it by changing some option in the interface builder to 'iOS 7 and later'